# How can I make Bootstrap dropdown menu show only on click not hover?

Tags: navigation

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap theme for Drupal. I need to show the dropdown menus only when the user clicks on the parent level, not when hovering, and make it disappear when clicks again.

What do I have to do to achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean the Bootstrap THEME? (not module) http://drupal.org/project/bootstrap

Comment: Yes sorry, Bootstrap theme not module, I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: Are they opening on hover for you right now? Because I don't think that happens automatically in the Bootstrap theme. I had to set my menu items to "expanded" in order for me to be able to click to open them, but they never opened on hover automatically.

Comment: Also, what version are you using? Drupal 7? Drupal 8?

Comment: I'm using the Drupal 7 version. I didn't have to add anything to work on hover with the Bootstrap theme. I think it's a better behaviour but my client prefers to open dropdown menus only when they click on the menu item.